# iOS simulator stopped listening by Charles/Proxyman

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, charles-proxy, proxyman

Today any of my iOS simulators stopped being listened by proxy app (Charles or Proxyman, any) after few minutes after fresh adding to Xcode. (Mac OS Ventura)

1. I do all needed preparations with the certificates, and **everything works**.
2. I can see all decoded traffic in proxy app just perfectly.
3. **After few minutes** traffic just **stop appearing** in proxy app. And nothing helps (simulators restart, Mac reboot etc.)
4. I have to remove app from simulator and reinstall from XCode, or reinstall simulator to have another few minutes of working proxy.

Any ideas how to solve this trouble and what is causing it?

Comment: Are you using the paid version of those proxies?

Comment: Why are you asking? Any difference? Not paid versions do not work at all officially?

Comment: I think its an iOS 16 issue. See this one: https://github.com/ProxymanApp/Proxyman/issues/1293

Comment: @lindanordstrom I think that's different bug. In my case I can install certificate and Proxyman can listen traffic fine for some short period of time. Then SSL handshake failed appears and I have to reinstall app from XCode. No certificate reinstall needed. Btw, it works fine on Mac OS Monterey.

Comment: https://docs.proxyman.io/troubleshooting/ios-16-devices-issues

Comment: Have you resolved your problem? I'm experiencing the same and it turned out that when I switch to my iPhone's hot spot, it works every time. From my wifi it doesn't work.

Comment: @WojciechKulik For now everything seems to work fine. I believe this issue was fixed in one of Mac OS or XCode updates. Now I have all latest versions and no issue anymore.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've got latest version of Xcode and macOS but the issue still occurs :(